# Is maximal subgroup unique?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> **Claim:** *If there is an homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ (finite group) to $S_n$ and $G/\ker (\phi) \cong A_n $ then the maximal subgroup of $G$ is unique.*

**Question:** Is the above claim true?

Comment: Is $G$ finite? Do you already know cases where this is true? That might help.

Comment: It is given that $G$ is finite .

Comment: Does $A_n$ have a unique maximal subgroup to begin with?

Comment: I know that $A_n$ have a unique maximal subgroup. But I don't know this thing is true for $G$ or not.

Comment: Consider the case $n=2$, then $\phi$ is trivial. $G$ can be any finite group. For example $G=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$, it has more than one maximal subgroup.

Comment: @sssss No, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205590/maximal-subgroups-of-of-the-alternating-group-of-degree-5

Comment: Sorry for late edit $G$ is non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It is not restrictive to assume that the image of $\phi$ is $A_n$ (the unique subgroup of $S_n$ of index $2$).

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $A_n$, which has several of them when $n\ge5$ (why?). Then $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ and the correspondence theorem says that distinct subgroups of $A_n$ have distinct inverse images.

Comment: @sssss No, why? You get at least as many maximal subgroups as there are in $A_n$.

Comment: @sssss Not at all.

Answer (score 1):

A conjugate of a maximal subgroup is again maximal. Thus if the maximal subgroup is unique, it is normal. (And the quotient is some $\mathbb Z/p$.)

$A_n$ has no nontrivial normal subgroups for $n\geq5$, so the inclusion of $A_n$ gives a counter-example.